Determine whether a class has a member function with a specific name where the member function can be overloaded
Is it possible to detect whether a class has a member function with a specific name?  Note, that the parameter list of the function doesn't matter, and the function can even be a template function, or the function name can be overloaded.
Detecting whether a member function exists with a known parameter list seems to be easy by using requires:
#include <cstdio>

struct Foo {
    void something(int);
};

template <typename TYPE>
concept has_something = requires(TYPE t) { t.something(42); };

int main() {
    printf("has_something: %d\n", has_something<Foo>);
}

But I'd like to detect whether a function exists with any parameter list. If I remove the int parameter from something, has_something will be false.
(I tried to use member pointers in requires, like &TYPE::something;, but it doesn't work if something is overloaded, as the expression is ambiguous. Not to mention that it doesn't work with template functions either.)

Dupes: Check if a class has a method with a given name but any signature and How to check if a member name (variable or function) exists in a class, with or without specifying type?. New answers can be added in the dupe.

@user12002570: it does, because that question has been answered, accepted, and it doesn't solve my problem.

@user12002570: you will get a compilation error, because taking the address of the function is ambiguous.

@user12002570: "can show". Sure. How?

Regardless of whether a solution can be found or not, I would like to suggest that you think about WHY you actually need this information. Other than printing a yes/no result, I don't really see much use -- C++ is a rather static and strictly typed language, so you can't call functions with "any" signature anyway (with useful parameters)... even if you know that one exists.

@user12002570: I mentioned this fact two times, even mentioned that the solution based on member function pointers doesn't work. I also mentioned templates, for which member function pointers don't work either.

You make a helper class that inherits from Foo and contains its own something() and using Foo::something;, and then check if &Derived::somethinig is well-formed (if it is, then Foo had no function). It's a weird way to do it, and doesn't work on final classes, but I don't know any other solutions.

@geza I've edited the title so that it highlight the main problem. The question is interesting.

@HolyBlackCat: I had this idea as well, but the problem is that using Foo::something doesn't compile, if Foo doesn't have something. Maybe it is possible to nudge the compiler somehow to ignore this error, but I failed to do so.

@geza Re: "I'd like to detect whether a function exists with any parameter list" and "the function can even be a template function" - If you call it "function template" instead (as you should) it becomes clearer that without template parameters, there is no function.  You'd need to test with all possible template parameters (which approches an infinite number of combinations) to make that test.

If C++26 actually does get reflection in C++26 that might give you an option.  Without that you would have to try an infinite number of combinations to see if the overload exists.

@TedLyngmo: A negative answer is an answer as well. "This cannot be done with current C++". The compiler can do this test, so in theory we doesn't need to test infinite combinations. And note, HolyBlackCat's idea almost works as far as I understand, and maybe it is even possible to make it work, I just don't know how. That's why I put this question.

@ChristianStieber: In short: I'd like to have this feature for avoiding programming errors. In a particular point in a template function, the user of the function may expect that something will be called by the template function (that's why the user added something as a member function). But the template function won't call it, because if something exists at that point, it means a programming error, something is not consistent. So I only want to have this feature for detecting programming errors. Like static_assert(!has_something<Foo>);

@geza But in that assertion, you would most likely want to check that is has a specific something function since having the wrong something is also a programming error.

Is there a maximum arity above which you are happy to have false negatives for? i.e. std::apply(&Foo::something, std::array<Bar, 100>) being valid, but has_something<Foo> reporting false?

@TedLyngmo: no, it is more complicated than that. The template function may call different versions of something depending on a lot of things. And some point, no something should exist. Yes, in theory, I could check whether no something exist from the list that the function would call. But as I want to detect programming errors, this is not enough, because at that point in the template function, any existence of something clearly means a programming error, and should be detected.

@Caleth: yes, that helps for my case. something won't have more than 5-6 parameters. And this is only for avoiding programming errors, so if some rare case is not caught, it's fine.

simply use std::is_member_function_pointer<>, as in: template <typename T> concept has_something =    std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(&T::something)>;

@MichaëlRoy No that won't work here. Demo. OP already knows how to do this for non-overloaded member function. They're asking for the case when the member function are overloaded. Your solution won't work for overloaded case. Demo

Here's a solution that will work for overloads, within the limits set by the number of parameters you define the concept for.
For templates, one naive way could be to define one concept per number of parameters, since one must instantiate the template function to be able to do anything with it.  The problem is that you must provide types, and templates may have unforeseen/unhandled restrictions on their input types.
Ex:
template<typename T>
concept has_templated_something_2 = requires(T t) {
    t.something(int{}, int{});    // only works if template accepts ints
};

If you can live with that, then the code below will give you an idea of what needs doing.
Because of this limitation, the code below only handles regular member functions and their overloads.  It is type-safe by design, so you can use the return of signatureN to check for specific argument types in th signatures if needed.
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdio>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

// some rather random types fgor testing...

struct Foo {
    void something();
    void something(int);
};

struct Foo2 {
    int something(int);
};

struct Foo3 {
    void something(int, int);
};

struct Foo4 {
    void something();
    void something(int, double);
};

struct Foo5 {
    void something(int);
    void something(int, double);
    void something(int, double, const char*, int, int);
};

// spot-checking virtual functions.
struct Bar {
    virtual void something(int, float);
    virtual void something(int, float, int) = 0;
};

// templates do not work.  in theory, you could try concepts with random types, 
// using a similar technique as below, with one concept per number of args, but 
// that would break as soon as a template would set restrictions on its input types.

struct BarT {
    template <typename A>
    void something(A a) {};
};

struct BarT2 {
    template <typename A, std::integral B>  // this type of restriction makes the task impossible (for me at least).
    void something(A, B){};                 // maybe someone will have an idea.
};

struct None {};

// -------------------------------------------

namespace some_details {

// this is where most of the grinding takes place.  It's a bit old school, but
// concepts do not readily accept std::enable_if 

// You must supply arguments to properly detect overloads, so add more if needed.

template <typename T, typename Ret, typename... A>
Ret return_type(Ret (T::*)(A...));

template <typename T, typename R>
std::tuple<R> signature0(R (T::*)());

template <typename T, typename R, typename A>
std::tuple<R, A> signature1(R (T::*)(A));

template <typename T, typename R, typename A, typename B>
std::tuple<R, A, B> signature2(R (T::*)(A, B));

template <typename T, typename R, typename A, typename B, typename C>
std::tuple<R, A, B, C> signature3(R (T::*)(A, B, C));

template <typename T, typename R, typename A, typename B, typename C,
          typename D>
std::tuple<R, A, B, C, D> signature4(R (T::*)(A, B, C, D));

template <typename T, typename R, typename A, typename B, typename C,
          typename D, typename E>
std::tuple<R, A, B, C, D, E> signature5(R (T::*)(A, B, C, D, E));

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_no_args : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct has_no_args<T, std::enable_if_t<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(signature0(&T::something))> == 1>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_1_arg : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct has_1_arg<T, std::enable_if_t<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(signature1(&T::something))> == 2>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_2_args : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct has_2_args<T, std::enable_if_t<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(signature2(&T::something))> == 3>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_3_args : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct has_3_args<T, std::enable_if_t<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(signature3(&T::something))> == 4>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_4_args : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct has_4_args<T, std::enable_if_t<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(signature4(&T::something))> == 5>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_5_args : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct has_5_args<T, std::enable_if_t<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(signature5(&T::something))> == 6>> : std::true_type {};

}  // namespace some_details


// main concept

template <typename T>
concept has_something =
    some_details::has_no_args<T>::value || some_details::has_1_arg<T>::value ||
    some_details::has_2_args<T>::value || some_details::has_3_args<T>::value ||
    some_details::has_4_args<T>::value || some_details::has_5_args<T>::value;

// that's about 75 lines of code for a concept.


int main() {
    // clang-format off
    using namespace some_details;  // for debugging.

    printf("#args  0   1   2   3   4   5    has...\n");
    printf("Foo:   %d   %d   %d   %d   %d   %d    %d\n", has_no_args<Foo>::value,   has_1_arg<Foo>::value,   has_2_args<Foo>::value,  has_3_args<Foo>::value,  has_4_args<Foo>::value,  has_5_args<Foo>::value,  has_something<Foo>);
    printf("Foo2:  %d   %d   %d   %d   %d   %d    %d\n", has_no_args<Foo2>::value,  has_1_arg<Foo2>::value,  has_2_args<Foo2>::value, has_3_args<Foo2>::value, has_4_args<Foo2>::value, has_5_args<Foo2>::value, has_something<Foo2>);
    printf("Foo3:  %d   %d   %d   %d   %d   %d    %d\n", has_no_args<Foo3>::value,  has_1_arg<Foo3>::value,  has_2_args<Foo3>::value, has_3_args<Foo3>::value, has_4_args<Foo3>::value, has_5_args<Foo3>::value, has_something<Foo3>);
    printf("Foo4:  %d   %d   %d   %d   %d   %d    %d\n", has_no_args<Foo4>::value,  has_1_arg<Foo4>::value,  has_2_args<Foo4>::value, has_3_args<Foo4>::value, has_4_args<Foo4>::value, has_5_args<Foo4>::value, has_something<Foo4>);
    printf("Foo5:  %d   %d   %d   %d   %d   %d    %d\n", has_no_args<Foo5>::value,  has_1_arg<Foo5>::value,  has_2_args<Foo5>::value, has_3_args<Foo5>::value, has_4_args<Foo5>::value, has_5_args<Foo5>::value, has_something<Foo5>);
    printf("Bar:   %d   %d   %d   %d   %d   %d    %d\n", has_no_args<Bar>::value,   has_1_arg<Bar>::value,   has_2_args<Bar>::value,  has_3_args<Bar>::value,  has_4_args<Bar>::value,  has_5_args<Bar>::value,  has_something<Bar>);
    printf("BarT:  %d   %d   %d   %d   %d   %d    %d\n", has_no_args<BarT>::value,  has_1_arg<BarT>::value,  has_2_args<BarT>::value, has_3_args<BarT>::value, has_4_args<BarT>::value, has_5_args<BarT>::value, has_something<BarT>);
    printf("None:  %d   %d   %d   %d   %d   %d    %d\n", has_no_args<None>::value,  has_1_arg<None>::value,  has_2_args<None>::value, has_3_args<None>::value, has_4_args<None>::value, has_5_args<None>::value, has_something<None>);

    // clang-format on
}

Outputs:
#args  0   1   2   3   4   5    has...
Foo:   1   1   0   0   0   0    1
Foo2:  0   1   0   0   0   0    1
Foo3:  0   0   1   0   0   0    1
Foo4:  1   0   1   0   0   0    1
Foo5:  0   1   1   0   0   1    1
Bar:   0   0   1   1   0   0    1
BarT:  0   0   0   0   0   0    0
None:  0   0   0   0   0   0    0

You can play with the code here: https://godbolt.org/z/rdfrY3bf9
